# Add legend to pyplot.errorbar

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# example data
x = np.arange(0.1, 4, 0.5)
y = np.exp(-x)
yerr = 0.1*np.random.rand(8)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.errorbar(x, y, linestyle='none', marker='*', yerr=yerr)
plt.show()
```

Hi, everyone! The goal is to add legend to the chart. y and yerr are labelled as 'mean' and 'std.Dev', respectively.

Comment: What have you tried? How is adding a `label="mean ± sd"` and calling `ax.legend()` is not satisfactory?

Comment: @DizietAsahi It's a good solution. Another question is, how to type the underscored plus sign?